# How to change the background of the validation message in a DropdownButtonFormField widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, theming

I'm using DropdownButtonFormField widget, but I can't find a way to change that color

[image: Screenshot]

I tried adding some values in inputDecoration but it didn't work, also changing some dataTheme values but I don't know if I changed the right ones.